# Proof of an interesting property of complex conjugates.

Tags: complex-numbers

In a mathematical methods class we were told the following:

$z= \frac{2+i}{(1+i)^i}$

Then the conjugate of the expression on the left of the equation is the RHS with the signs of the i's reversed. eg:

$\overline{z}= \frac{2-i}{(1-i)^{-i}}$

Can someone prove this fact to me?

Comment: I suspect that complex conjugation isn't compatible with _everything_ you can make up, so your asserted "fact" is false.

Comment: That is what I was told in class.

Comment: And a mathematician does not reject something based on suspicion

Comment: And I'm telling you that this has a caveat.

Comment: Sure. can you provide a counter example so I can ask my proffessor?

Comment: I only asked in the first place because I find it weird myself

Comment: That depends on what you allow $f$ to look like. Think about piecewise functions.

Comment: forget about f if it bothers you so much what about the numbers?

Comment: What I was told about f is that it has real domain

Comment: Isn't the conjugate defined to be the same number with the $i$s having opposite signs?

Comment: and im not in an advanced class.

Comment: conjugate is same real and opposite sign on imaginary part

Comment: Yes, so what is your question?

Comment: @vounoo In principle, yes $\overline{f(z)} = \Re f(z) - i \Im f(z)$, but that's not what you're doing when replacing $i$ by $-i$.

Comment: z=Real + i Imaginary, with real and imaginary being real so if you have a complicated expression it is hard to express it in this form that you can take conjugate from the definition and apparently you dont have too because of what I write in the question, and I want to see a proof of that

Comment: ok. I tell you my professor actually told me that. unless you can prove it is false stop commenting

Comment: and if it is so obvious to you why not just prove it?

Comment: let $F(x)=\operatorname{Im}(ix)=x$. Then $\overline{F(x)}=x$, but replacing $i$ by $-i$ gives $\operatorname{Im}(-ix)=-x$.

Comment: I need to ask again about the function I edit my question

Comment: Since most elementary operations behave well under conjugation (sum, subtraction, product, division, exponentiation), any expression involving only these operations (and nothing else) will obey that rule whenever $x$ is real. However, this will not work for more complicated expressions (such as @jgon's).

Comment: I am not quite convinced... what you told me is very vague...

Comment: I think the result lies in $\ln z = \ln |z| + i \arg z$ and $\ln \bar{z} = \ln |z| - i \arg z = \overline{\ln z}$. Then it becomes pretty obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The Conjugate

The conjugate is an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ that fixes all the real numbers. what this means is that $\overline{wz}=\overline{w}\cdot\overline{z}$, $\overline{w+z}=\overline{w}+\overline{z}$, $\overline{x}=x$, and $\overline{1/z}=1/\overline{z}$ for all complex numbers $w$ and $z$ and a real number $x$.

In turn what this means is that for any expression which only has addition multiplication and division and where all variables are real, then you can keep expressing the conjugate in terms of the conjugates of the subexpressions to get that the conjugate of the expression is the same expression with all the $i$s replaced with $-i$.

### Functions:

As I mentioned in my comment, not all functions from $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ have this property.

If $F(x)=\operatorname{Im}(ix)=x$ then $\overline{F(x)}=x$, but replacing $i$ by $-i$ gives $\operatorname{Im}(-ix)=-x$.

However, if you can write a function of a complex number as a power series with real coefficients, $\displaystyle f(z)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i z^i$, then

$\displaystyle \overline{f(z)}=\overline{\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i z^i}=\overline{\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^n a_i z^i}$, by the definition of an infinite sum as the limit of the partial sums,

$\displaystyle = \lim_{n\to\infty} \overline{\sum_{i=0}^n a_i z^i}$, by the continuity of conjugation,

$\displaystyle =\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^n \overline{a_i}\cdot\overline{z}^i$ since conjugation is a homomorphism

$\displaystyle =\sum_{i=0}^\infty  a_i \overline{z}^i = f(\overline{z})$.

This assumes all the series converge and stuff, but assuming that, then this works. In particular this works for $\sin z$, $\cos z$, and $e^z$.

Therefore $\overline{e^{x+iy}}=e^{x-iy}$ like we wanted. I'm not sure about $\tan^{-1}$ off the top of my head, check to see if there is a series. However, since $\tan(x+iy)=\frac{\sin(x+iy)}{\cos(x+iy)}$, $\overline{\tan(x+iy)}=\tan(x-iy)$.

Comment: thank you. Thank you for covering the function part as well. So the exponentiation in the number case is false ? (eg see the example I gave in the question)

Comment: @vounoo Exponentiation seems to be ok: since $a^b$ is defined as $e^{b\ln a}$, the conjugate of this is $e^{\overline{b\ln a}}=e^{\overline{b}\cdot\overline{\ln a}} = e^{\overline{b}\ln\overline{a}}=\overline{a}^{\overline{b}}$ where the log identity comes from obareey's comment on your question.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\conj}{\overline}$
This is meant as a complement to jgon's great answer (and to some of the comments in the OP's post):

Let's say that a function (or operation) with $n$ complex parameters $f(z_1,z_2, \ldots, z_n)$ *behaves well under conjugation* if $\conj{f(z_1, \ldots, z_n)} = f(\conj{z_1}, \conj{z_2}, \ldots, \conj{z_n})$.

This is true for unary minus $z \mapsto -z$, for addition $(z,w) \mapsto z + w$, multiplication, division, exponentiation $z \mapsto e^z$, among many others.

Now what is an expression involving only "well-behaved" operations? Well, it's something like this:
$$\frac{z + e^{z + iz}}{z^3 - 7i} = d(s(z,\exp(s(z,p(i,z)))),s(f(z),p(-7,i))),$$
a big composition of the operations $d(z,w) = z/w$, $s(z,w) = s + w$, $p(z,w) = zw$, $\exp(z) = e^z$.

The point is that composition of well-behaved operators is well-behaved! Therefore, conjugating a big composition of well-behaved operators whose parameters are real numbers together with $i$ amounts to conjugating each individual parameter, such that every $i$ becomes a $-i$, as your professor claimed. However, this does not work for more complicated expressions, as others have already shown.

Answer (score 0):

We have the following definitions and calculs

[image]

Then it is clear that the conjugate of the multivalued function of the denominator is

[image]. The other part is evident.