# Taking the complex conjugate of some complicated composite function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm aware of the rule where to take the complex conjugate of anything, you simply replace any $i$'s with $-i$, and to conjugate any composed functions (i.e. $f*(g(z))=f(g*(z)))$

What is the mathematical justification for this?  And there certain situations where this rule would not work?

According to to Wikipedia,

$$
\phi(\bar{z})=\overline{\phi(z)}
$$

Is true when $\phi$ is holomorphic and $\phi(z)$ is defined.  The article on holomorphic functions mentions that it is essentially the same as analytic functions, so does this mean that this rule may not apply for, say, non-infinitely differentiable functions, like functions with discontinuities?

I'm asking because during my QM exam, I conjugated an integral, by taking the conjugation inside the integral, and basically followed the rule and replaced any i with -i, and any $\psi$ with $\psi$* and vice versa.

Comment: Related: this question and my answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1266933/proof-of-an-interesting-property-of-complex-conjugates/1266996#1266996

Comment: Thanks, that certainly clears things up.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you read that $\overline{\phi(z)}=\phi(\overline{z})$? That's not even true with the condition that $\phi(z)$ is holomorphic. For example the constant function $\phi(z)=i$.

Comment: In general I think you need the condition that the power series for the function has real coefficients.

Comment: Oh there was the additional criteria on the wikipedia article that phi is a holomorphic function "whose restriction to the real numbers is real valued" though I'm not sure what that means.